# Understanding Sylvester's theorems and change of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, coordinate-systems, quadratic-forms

> (Sylvester's Theorem). Any quadratic form $q$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with matrix $A$ has the form \begin{equation}q({\bf{v}}) = \sum_{i=1}^t {x^2 _i} - \sum_{i=1}^u x^2_{t+i}\end{equation} with respect to a suitable basis, where $t + u = \text{rank}(A)$.
>
> Equivalently, given a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, there is an invertible matrix $P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $P^TAP = B$, where $D = (\alpha_{ij})$
>   is a diagonal matrix with $\alpha_{ii}
> = 1$ for
>   $1 \leq i \leq t$, $\alpha_{ii} = -1$ for $t + 1 \leq i \leq t + u$, and $\alpha_{ii} = 0$ for $t + u + 1 \leq i \leq n$, and
>   $t + u = \text{rank}(A)$.

I am trying to understand the above and why I would want to perform this coordinate change when I can diagonalise it instead. I tried an example with $q(x,y) = -x^2 + 6xy -9y^2$ :

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ 3 & -9 \end{pmatrix}, \lambda_1 = -10, v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \\ \frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}}\end{pmatrix}, \lambda_2 = 0, v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\end{pmatrix}$$

$$S = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \\ \frac{-3}{\sqrt{10}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \end{pmatrix}, S^TAS = \begin{pmatrix} -10 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \Lambda$$

Correct me if I am wrong, but from here I believe the normal "nice" change of coordinates ignoring the above theorem is defining:

$$q(x,y) = {\bf{x}}^TA{\bf{x}} = {\bf{x}}^TS\Lambda S^T{\bf{x}} := {\bf{x'}}^T\Lambda{\bf{x'}} = r(x',y')$$

And because $S$ is an orthogonal matrix this means the quadratic form is preserved under the new $(x',y')$ coordinates.

However if we write for Sylvester's theorem:

$$Q = \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{10} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, D = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

To factorise $\Lambda$ as $\Lambda = QDQ^T \iff A = SQD(SQ)^T$ and defining $P:= S{(Q^{-1})}^T = SQ^{-1}$ verifies there does indeed exist an invertible (but not orthogonal!) $P$ s.t. $P^T A P = D$. We also have by the theorem there must be a coordinate change for $q({\bf{v}}) = -x^2$

The new coordinates $(x'', y'')$ defined by ${\bf{x}}^TSQD (SQ)^T{\bf{x}} := {\bf{x''}}^TD{\bf{x''}}$ I computed as $(x-3y, 0)$ which gives $q(x,y)$ multiplying out the matrix vector product.

But the matrix $SQ$ is not orthogonal, $SQ(SQ)^T = SQQ^T S^T = SQ^2 S^{-1} \neq I$ which must mean the transformation deforms whatever geometric shape $q$ represents, is there some sort of geometric meaning to this or application? Sylvester's Law of Inertia which I am told is also an important result tells me that the $t$ and $u$ amounts of $\pm 1$ are invariant under any transformation in the form described in the box above, which implies there are many such transformations, how else would I find these?

Comment: I've noticed this post has gotten a lot of views, so I guess I wasn't the only one confused by the point of this funny little theorem, especially if it is stated in isolation like in the linear algebra course at my university. With hindsight of a couple years on my side I'll just put a note here that this is indeed a useful theorem. As mentioned in the answers, it is great for differential geometry, since it means if you have an inner product that smoothly varies i.e. the entries are functions, then it means the signature isn't going to randomly change.

Comment: *continued* This is especially good for general relativity, where your "generalised inner product" might locally look like diag$(-1,1,1,1)$ at a point, and you want it to be that way at all points, since the -1 corresponds to time and the +1s as space. If there was no "inertia" of the signature and the $\pm$1s wandered all over the place then you would have no good consistent concept of spacetime. Similarly, a geometer would be upset if their smoothly varying inner product diag$(1,1,1,1)$ randomly stopped being positive definite at a point, but thank goodness no! The +1s are inert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to begin with orthogonal matrices, which may become difficult to find in dimension 3, 4, or higher.

If the original matrix $H$ is all integers, or all rational, we can find a **rational** matrix $P$ with $\det P = \pm 1$ so that $P^T HP = D$ is diagonal. The resulting $D$ will obey [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia). The diagonal entries need not be the eigenvalues.

If the nonzero diagonal entries of $D$ are not all $\pm 1,$ you may then use a diagonal matrix $R$ with entries the reciprocals of some square roots, so that $R^T P^T HPR$ is of the desired form.

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 - 1 & 3 \\ 
3 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 & 0 \\ 
 - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
 - 1 & 3 \\ 
3 &  - 9 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: So one of the uses is that we can diagonalise without obtaining matrices with elements outside a field we were working in? In which situations would $D$ contain elements that are not $\pm 1$, doesn't the theorem guarantee this?

Comment: @TheoDiamantakis the theorem says you can arrange $\pm 1$ if you allow any sort of real numbers in the change of basis. If we start with everything rational, at worst the necessary coordinates involve square roots of rational numbers. When the diagonal entry of $D$ is $a < 0,$ we then multiply on right and left by $1/\sqrt{|a|}$

Comment: Thank you I think that makes sense, thank you for both your answers.

Answer (score 2):

> "Why would I perform this coordinate change when I can diagonalize
>   instead?"

Sometimes we don't want to actually perform the coordinate change; we just want to know that such a change exists. As @WillJagy points out, Sylvester's law says that not only is there such a coordinate change, but the number of $+1$ entries (sometimes called the "signature") is the same for *any* such coordinate change.

Here's my favorite application:

Take a smooth compact surface without boundary $S$ in 3-space. Consider the function 
$$
f_v: S \to \Bbb R : (x, y, z) \mapsto (x, y, z) \cdot v
$$
For almost every unit vector $v$, this will be a smooth function. To simplify, let's suppose that $v = (0,0,1)$ works, so that $f(x, y, z) = z$.

Now the second derivative of $f$ at each point $P = (x, y, z) \in S$ is a symmetric bilinear form on the tangent plane to $S$ at $P$. If we look at  each critical point $Q$ of $f$ (for a sphere, that'd be "the south pole" and "the north pole"), this signature tells you whether the surface 'bends down' at $Q$ (as at the north pole) or "bends up" at $Q$ (as in the south pole, or "bends both ways" (as in the two middle critical points for a bagel that's balanced vertically on a table). It doesn't matter how *much* the surface bends up or down, hence I don't care about the eigenvalues; all that matters is that in every direction at the south pole, it's bending *up*. And the signature tells me that.

The cool theorem? The sum (over all critical points) of $(-1)^{\sigma(Q)}$, where $\sigma(Q)$ is the signature, is the same as the Euler characteristic of the surface.

This is all laid out in detail (along with the technical hypotheses required for it to work, like "critical points of $f$ must be isolated") in the first chapter of Milnor's *Morse Theory*.

Comment: So essentially it acts as a different way to test positive definiteness of the second derivative? The existence often being useful and not the actual coordinate transform makes more sense. Also I might have misunderstood the statement of the law of inertia, is it true it holds for any coordinate transform and not just the special case where cross terms are eliminated?

Comment: Thanks, Will -- very cool!